# Adobe Acrobat 8 Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have downloaded Adobe Acrobat 8 Pro and am following the Q&A comments, my question is when opening the programme it says I have to register. Is this a must, given that it is no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/download/office-business/adobe-acrobat-professional-80-3328874/):

Adobe Acrobat Professional 8.0

It's the 2006 edition of Acrobat - yours, for free

You'll be asked for your registration details. Enter your name and (optionally) company, and use the serial number **1118-1414-1955-8737-8172-0350** . Click Next > Next.

Comment: Thanks lot, will help me in publishing our regimental newsletters

Comment: You are welcome! If an answer helps to solve the problem, consider to mark it as "accepted" (I mean an answer in general, not only the current one).